# write a btach file to copy files from one network folder to another network folder

Tags: batch-file

I am having a pdf storage folder on network in which all users used to store their all files for sharing each other . Now I need to copy all those files from that folder to another folder which is on same network but on different server.

Answer (score 2):

Use xcopy and pass in the UNC path of the source and destination.  For help on xcopy, run:

```
xcopy /?
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more precise regarding your OSes, because i think that the answers may vary greatly depending on it.

If it's a windows box, i'd recommend the use of robocopy, which can handle retries, mirroring, speed capping and much more. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy.exe available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

**example:**

robocopy \\server1\c$\sourcedir \\server2\backup\server1 /MIR

Answer (score 0):

You will run into problems if any network files are in use at the time of the copy. Make sure you talk with your network administrator and managers to arrange a time that users can leave that directory alone so that your copy will complete without any exceptions.